How to import Pinia into html file for display vue3 component?
I have basic vue app of 3 components with Pinia store. I need export it and use exported .js file to display component in basic html file. Without Pinia implemenation it works well, but I need this store. App in run dev mode with store works well too. So problem is in import Pinia and call probebly this:
const pinia = Pinia.createPinia();
app.use(pinia);
I build it with: npm run build
vite.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: './src/App.vue',
      name: 'MyComponent',
      fileName: (format) => `my-component.${format}.js`
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['vue'],
      output: {
        globals: {
          vue: 'Vue'
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

main.js file in vueApp
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import { createPinia } from 'pinia';
import App from './App.vue';

const app = createApp(App);
const pinia = createPinia();

app.use(pinia);
app.mount('#app');

Error

ReferenceError: Pinia is not defined

HTML file:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Vue Component in HTML</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
      <my-component></my-component>
  </div>

  <!-- Polyfill process.env for browser compatibility -->
  <script>
    window.process = {
      env: { NODE_ENV: 'production' }
    };
  </script>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/pinia@2.0.0-beta.0/dist/pinia.iife.js"></script> 
  <script src="dist/my-component.umd.js"></script>

  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      console.log(Vue);
      console.log(Pinia);
      console.log(window.Pinia);

      const app = Vue.createApp({});
      const pinia = Pinia.createPinia();
      app.use(pinia);
      app.component('my-component', MyComponent);
      app.mount('#app');
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>


The problem that was discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/78591715 still persists. There is no unpkg.com/pinia@2.0.0-beta.0/dist/pinia.iife.js so it's not loaded, this is the reason there's no Pinia var. It's either Vite or CDN, as said. It's unknown why you tried to use both. Generally this "document.addEventListener(..." isn't needed, this duplicates what's done in main.js

Your Pinia version doesn't exist, use the latest - 2.1.7 and I would suggest using an import map:


<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Vue Component in HTML</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
      <my-component></my-component>
  </div>

  <!-- Polyfill process.env for browser compatibility -->
  <script>
    window.process = {
      env: { NODE_ENV: 'production' }
    };
  </script>
  <script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "vue": "https://play.vuejs.org/vue.esm-browser.js",
      "@vue/devtools-api": "https://unpkg.com/@vue/devtools-api@6/lib/esm/index.js",
      "vue-demi": "https://unpkg.com/vue-demi@0.13.11/lib/index.mjs?raw",
      "pinia": "https://unpkg.com/pinia@2.1.7/dist/pinia.esm-browser.js"
    },
    "scopes": {}
  }
  </script>

  <script type="module">
    import {createApp} from 'vue';
    import {createPinia} from 'pinia';
      const app =createApp({});
      const pinia = createPinia();
      app.use(pinia);
      app.component('my-component', {template: '<h1>Hello world!</h1>'});
      app.mount('#app');
  </script>
</body>




Hey looks like the Pinia is working well. However, I still have a question about importing MyComponent. I can't get it to work.
I tried:

import './dist/my-component.umd.js';
import './dist/my-component.umd.js';
import {MyComponent} from './dist/my-component.umd.js';
import MyComponent from './dist/my-component.umd.js';
Unfortunately, none of this works :(
SyntaxError: The requested module './dist/my-component.umd.js' does not provide an export named 'MyComponent' (at site.html:33:13)
